# Jquery google maps api Function inside a function

Tags: jquery

Im using google maps api v3, and I have a database which contains some address.I have two scripts that I can use for doing it. One for Draw in the map the waypoints and other one for convert the address to latitude and longitude. For draw the waypoings, I need to convert the address to latiude and longitute, but I cant use one function inside the other.

The waypoints script:

```
jQuery(function() {
var stops = [
                    {"Geometry":{"Latitude":-22.884820,"Longitude":-47.060935}},
                    {"Geometry":{"Latitude":-22.876644,"Longitude":-47.048631}}
                ] ;

var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));

// new up complex objects before passing them around
var directionsDisplay = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
var directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();

Tour_startUp(stops);

window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay);
window.tour.fitBounds(map);

if (stops.length > 1)
    window.tour.calcRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
 });
```

The function to convert address to lat and long:

```
function codeAddress(add) {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = add;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

  return "{Geometry:{Latitude:"+results[0].geometry.location.lat() + ",Longitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lng()}};

  } 

  else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have given the GPS location using google api

function initMap(emp_id,dateofloc) {

```
$.ajax({            
    url: "GPS.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:"emp_id="+emp_id+"&dateofloc="+dateofloc,
    success: function(result){

        var json = $.parseJSON(result); 
        var i=0;
        var locationsdetls='';
        var startlat1=0;
        var startlat2=0;
        var locations = [];
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
        $.each(json , function (index, value){                  

            var res1 = value.MSGText.split(",");
            var latitude = res1['0'].split("Lat:");
            var longitude = res1['1'].split("Long:");

            var latitude =latitude['1'].trim();
            var longitude=longitude['1'].trim();

            if(i==1)
            {
                startlat1=latitude;
                startlat2=longitude;                    
            }
            var local = [];
            local[0]=value.address;
            local[1]=latitude;
            local[2]=longitude;
            local[3]=i;                         
            locations[i]=local;     

             var triangleCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);          
             flightPlanCoordinates.push(triangleCoords);            


            i++;
        });



            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(startlat1,startlat2),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),             
            map: map    


        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
        }


    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);


   }});
```

}